# How to assign to a variable an infinite value in gekko?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to assign an infinite value to a variable of gekko. I have tried with the numpy's infinite value and python's own infinite but it is still not working due to a problem of recognition of gekko.

The main objective of this idea is to force a variable to be strictly equal to 0, at least in the first iteration of the solver.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import Inf
model=GEKKO()
R=model.FV(value=Inf)
T=model.Array(model.Var,2)
Q=model.FV()
model.Equation(Q==(T[1]-T[0])/R)
model.solve()
```

And the error I am getting:

```
Exception: @error: Model Expression
 *** Error in syntax of function string: Invalid element: inf
```

Moreover, sometimes other variables are also required to be infinite, again, variables that are located in the denominator of a model equation. This is quite useful in order to try different scenarios of the simulation I am working with and check the systems behavior.

Hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large-scale NLP and MINLP solvers don't know how to compute gradients with a `np.nan` value so initializing with `NaN` generally doesn't help. Please post example code that demonstrates the issue that you are observing with improved performance from `NaN` initialization.

Below are four unconstrained optimization methods compared on the same sample problem. The algorithms do not benefit from `NaN` for initialization. Some solvers substitute `NaN` with `0` or a high or low number. I suggest that you try giving `np.nan` as an initial condition to these solution methods to see how it affects the search for the minimum.

[image: quasi Newton methods]

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define objective function
def f(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    obj = x1**2 - 2.0 * x1 * x2 + 4 * x2**2
    return obj

# define objective gradient
def dfdx(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    grad = []
    grad.append(2.0 * x1 - 2.0 * x2)
    grad.append(-2.0 * x1 + 8.0 * x2)
    return grad

# Exact 2nd derivatives (hessian)
H = [[2.0, -2.0],[-2.0, 8.0]]

# Start location
x_start = [-3.0, 2.0]

# Design variables at mesh points
i1 = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.1)
i2 = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.1)
x1_mesh, x2_mesh = np.meshgrid(i1, i2)
f_mesh = x1_mesh**2 - 2.0 * x1_mesh * x2_mesh + 4 * x2_mesh**2

# Create a contour plot
plt.figure()
# Specify contour lines
lines = range(2,52,2)
# Plot contours
CS = plt.contour(x1_mesh, x2_mesh, f_mesh,lines)
# Label contours
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
# Add some text to the plot
plt.title(r'$f(x)=x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 + 4x_2^2$')
plt.xlabel(r'$x_1$')
plt.ylabel(r'$x_2$')

##################################################
# Newton's method
##################################################
xn = np.zeros((2,2))
xn[0] = x_start
# Get gradient at start location (df/dx or grad(f))
gn = dfdx(xn[0])
# Compute search direction and magnitude (dx)
#  with dx = -inv(H) * grad
delta_xn = np.empty((1,2))
delta_xn = -np.linalg.solve(H,gn)
xn[1] = xn[0]+delta_xn
plt.plot(xn[:,0],xn[:,1],'k-o')

##################################################
# Steepest descent method
##################################################
# Number of iterations
n = 8
# Use this alpha for every line search
alpha = 0.15
# Initialize xs
xs = np.zeros((n+1,2))
xs[0] = x_start
# Get gradient at start location (df/dx or grad(f))
for i in range(n):
    gs = dfdx(xs[i])
    # Compute search direction and magnitude (dx)
    #  with dx = - grad but no line searching
    xs[i+1] = xs[i] - np.dot(alpha,dfdx(xs[i]))
plt.plot(xs[:,0],xs[:,1],'g-o')

##################################################
# Conjugate gradient method
##################################################
# Number of iterations
n = 8
# Use this alpha for the first line search
alpha = 0.15
neg = [[-1.0,0.0],[0.0,-1.0]]
# Initialize xc
xc = np.zeros((n+1,2))
xc[0] = x_start
# Initialize delta_gc
delta_cg = np.zeros((n+1,2))
# Initialize gc
gc = np.zeros((n+1,2))
# Get gradient at start location (df/dx or grad(f))
for i in range(n):
    gc[i] = dfdx(xc[i])
    # Compute search direction and magnitude (dx)
    #  with dx = - grad but no line searching
    if i==0:
        beta = 0
        delta_cg[i] = - np.dot(alpha,dfdx(xc[i]))
    else:
        beta = np.dot(gc[i],gc[i]) / np.dot(gc[i-1],gc[i-1])
        delta_cg[i] = alpha * np.dot(neg,dfdx(xc[i])) + beta * delta_cg[i-1]
    xc[i+1] = xc[i] + delta_cg[i] 
plt.plot(xc[:,0],xc[:,1],'y-o')

##################################################
# Quasi-Newton method
##################################################
# Number of iterations
n = 8
# Use this alpha for every line search
alpha = np.linspace(0.1,1.0,n)
# Initialize delta_xq and gamma
delta_xq = np.zeros((2,1))
gamma = np.zeros((2,1))
part1 = np.zeros((2,2))
part2 = np.zeros((2,2))
part3 = np.zeros((2,2))
part4 = np.zeros((2,2))
part5 = np.zeros((2,2))
part6 = np.zeros((2,1))
part7 = np.zeros((1,1))
part8 = np.zeros((2,2))
part9 = np.zeros((2,2))
# Initialize xq
xq = np.zeros((n+1,2))
xq[0] = x_start
# Initialize gradient storage
g = np.zeros((n+1,2))
g[0] = dfdx(xq[0])
# Initialize hessian storage
h = np.zeros((n+1,2,2))
h[0] = [[1, 0.0],[0.0, 1]]
for i in range(n):
    # Compute search direction and magnitude (dx)
    #  with dx = -alpha * inv(h) * grad
    delta_xq = -np.dot(alpha[i],np.linalg.solve(h[i],g[i]))
    xq[i+1] = xq[i] + delta_xq

    # Get gradient update for next step
    g[i+1] = dfdx(xq[i+1])

    # Get hessian update for next step
    gamma = g[i+1]-g[i]
    part1 = np.outer(gamma,gamma)
    part2 = np.outer(gamma,delta_xq)
    part3 = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(part2),part1)

    part4 = np.outer(delta_xq,delta_xq)
    part5 = np.dot(h[i],part4)
    part6 = np.dot(part5,h[i])
    part7 = np.dot(delta_xq,h[i])
    part8 = np.dot(part7,delta_xq)
    part9 = np.dot(part6,1/part8)
    
    h[i+1] = h[i] + part3 - part9

plt.plot(xq[:,0],xq[:,1],'r-o')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('contour.png',dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

More information is available in the [design optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/QuasiNewton).

**Response to Edit**

Thanks for clarifying the question and for including a source code example.  While it isn't possible to include `Inf` as a guess, an equivalent form with an additional variable `x` may be able to accomplish the desired behavior. This sets the term `(T[1]-T[0])/R` initially equal to zero at the beginning iteration.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import Inf
model=GEKKO()
R=model.FV(value=1e20)
T=model.Array(model.Var,2)
x=model.Var(value=0)
Q=model.FV()
model.Equations([x==(T[1]-T[0])/R,
                 Q==x])
model.solve()
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you so much for answering. I have tried to clarify the question, sorry if I was not specific before.